# bindings break when instantiating viewmodel for applyBindings in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I must be missing something very simple, but I'm not seeing it.

I had a simple viewmodel:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observableArray([{id:'one',display:'ONE'},{id:'two',display:'TWO'}]);
    self.show_subcategories_for = function(category){
        alert(category.id);
    };
};     
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

and html for it:

```
<div id="categories">
    <!-- ko foreach: categories -->
    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: id }, click: show_subcategories_for" name="category" />
    <label data-bind="attr: { 'for': id }, text: display"></label>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

working jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/J8VNY/2/

Then I was trying to factor out categories array and wanted to pass it to the view model as a parameter, knockout would error out on "show_subcategories_for is not defined ", which is definitely there.

I changed the viewmodel to following:

```
var ViewModel = function(cats) {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observableArray(cats);
    self.show_subcategories_for = function(category){
        alert(category.id);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(
    [{id:'one',display:'ONE'},{id:'two',display:'TWO'}]
));
```

here is jsfiddle with the error: http://jsfiddle.net/J8VNY/1/

Everything appears to be correct yet for some reason instantiating viewmodel and passing it an array as a parameter causes knockout some confusion.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `$root` keyword:

```
<input type="radio"
       name="category"
       data-bind="attr: { id: id }, click: $root.show_subcategories_for" />
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: thanks, that works. Why is it necessary when the viewmodel is instantiated? Because it works ok in the first example.

Comment: root is a bit dangerous since its absolute and not relative. I would use $parent

Comment: In the first case you didn't really create a view-model at all, you just passed a function. If you'll run `ko.dataFor(document.body)` you'll get `undefined`, while in the second fiddle you'll get the view-model object.

Comment: The reason you see the results is because `self/this` in your function referred to `window` and the `data-bind` in your HTML is indeed using that data from the global scope (`window`).

Comment: also, why is using $root "a bit dangerous"?

Comment: I don't think it's 'dangerous', it can be misleading when your view-model is nested more than 2 levels and you're not careful enough. Yet, most people tend to define functions (behavior) on the `$root`, and in your case, `$parent === $root` anyway.